# Certain content not loading when scraping a site with Beautiful Soup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to scrape the ratings off recipes on NYT Cooking but having issues getting the content I need. When I look at the source on the NYT page, I see the following:

```
<div class="ratings-rating">
    <span class="ratings-header ratings-content">194 ratings</span>

    <div class="ratings-stars-wrap">
      <div class="ratings-stars ratings-content four-star-rating avg-rating">
```

The content I'm trying to pull out is `194 ratings` and `four-star-rating`. However, when I pull in the page source via Beautiful Soup I only see this:

```
 <div class="ratings-rating">
    <span class="ratings-header ratings-content"><%= header %></span>

    <div class="ratings-stars-wrap">
      <div class="ratings-stars ratings-content <%= ratingClass %> <%= state %>">
```

The code I'm using is:

```
url = 'https://cooking.nytimes.com/recipes/1020049-lemony-chicken-soup-with-fennel-and-dill'

r = get(url, headers = headers, timeout=15)
page_soup = soup(r.text,'html.parser')
```

Any thoughts why that information isn't pulling through?

Comment: You'll probably have to use a headless browser with selenium for instance to execute the javascript, because this content is loaded dynamically
you have the template at the end:
`<script id="recipe-ratings-tmpl" type="template">`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

much easier to use attribute = value selectors to grab from span with class `ratings-metadata`

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

data = requests.get('https://cooking.nytimes.com/recipes/1020049-lemony-chicken-soup-with-fennel-and-dill')
soup = BeautifulSoup(data.content, 'lxml')
rating = soup.select_one('[itemprop=ratingValue]').text
ratingCount = soup.select_one('[itemprop=ratingCount]').text
print(rating, ratingCount)
```

Comment: Sorry for the delay — just had a chance to test this out. This works and is simpler so accepting. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Try using below code

```
import requests
import lxml
from lxml import html
import re

url = "https://cooking.nytimes.com/recipes/1019706-spiced-roasted-cauliflower-with-feta-and-garlic?action=click&module=Recirculation%20Band%20Recipe%20Card&region=More%20recipes%20from%20Alison%20Roman&pgType=recipedetails&rank=1"

r = requests.get(url)
tree = html.fromstring(r.content)

t = tree.xpath('/html/body/script[14]')[0]

# look for value for bootstrap.recipe.avg_rating
m = re.search("bootstrap.recipe.avg_rating = ", t.text)
colon = re.search(";", t.text[m.end()::])
rating = t.text[m.end():m.end()+colon.start()]
print(rating)

# look for value for bootstrap.recipe.num_ratings = 
n = re.search("bootstrap.recipe.num_ratings = ", t.text)
colon2 = re.search(";", t.text[n.end()::])
star = t.text[n.end():n.end()+colon2.start()]
print(star)
```